# angular2 spring-boot project structure

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I have a new angular2 project that was built using the standard file structure described in the quickstart.  I am attempting to build an API gateway and have spring-boot host my application, however I haven't been able to configure boot to use the /dist directory in my project where the generated sources are created.  The project structure is as follows:

```
project  
|--dist  
|--node_modules
|--src  
|  |--app  
|  |--assets
|  |--main  
|  |  |--java  
|  |  |--resources
|  |  |  |--config  
|  |  |--webapp
|  |  |  |--WEB-INF
```

I would like to use the default /dist directory so that I can still use npm/webpack for continuous development on the UI.

I tried configuring the static resources directory like so:

```
 spring.resources.staticLocations: /dist
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

I created a resource handler to point directly to the dist directory:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    String currentPath = new File("./").getAbsolutePath();
    currentPath = "file:///" + currentPath;

   registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(currentPath + "/dist/");
  }
}
```

This solves part of the problem but now my root URL ('/') no longer maps to index.html.

Is there an easier/better way to configure spring-boot to find the /dist project directory?  Should my project structure change?  I would really like to get all of these pieces working together cleanly.

Comment: You need to be using a location from the classpath rather than trying to hit it on the disk directly. (It won't be there in the jar, after all!) I usually configure my JS pipeline to output into `target/classes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @chrylis advice and pointed the destination directory for the webpack build to build/dist (using Gradle).

I avoided putting the generated sources in `/resources/**` because eventually this will get built into a .war and deployed to an enterprise application server -- I didn't want a lot of include/exclude logic in my build to support this.  Plus the build directory seemed a more logical place for the generated .js source.

My project structure now looks like this:

```
project  
|--build
|  |--dist
|  |--...  
|--node_modules
|--src  
|  |--app  
|  |--assets
|  |--main  
|  |  |--java  
|  |  |--resources
|  |  |  |--config  
|  |  |--webapp
|  |  |  |--WEB-INF
```

I eliminated the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and configured the static resources to point to my dist directory in build:

```
spring.resources.static-locations: "file:./build/dist/"
```

I'm now able to run Webpack, Spring-Boot or deploy to my application server with the same source and very little configuration overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources
located within any of the following directories:

```
/META-INF/resources/

/resources/

/static/

/public/
```

The folders are relative to src/main/resources

If you put index.html like below, then spring can serve your file
without any configuration.

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/index.html

src/main/resources/resources/index.html

src/main/resources/static/index.html

src/main/resources/public/index.html
```